# Updating the UserProfile table in MVC 4 to include other columns-Entity Framework keeps assigning dbo. ahead of the table

Tags: vba, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

...at least I think that's what's happening.

I'm trying to use the UserProfile Table in my MVC website to hold more than just the userID and userName.

I'm sorry I'm a terrible noob and I know this is a poor hack of the example code, but here's what I've got in the AccountController:

```
    Public Function Register(ByVal model As RegisterModel) As ActionResult

        If ModelState.IsValid Then
        Using db As New UsersContext()
            ' Attempt to register the user
            Try
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password)
                WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password)

                Dim id As Integer = WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name)

                Dim userProfile As UserProfile = db.UserProfile.Find(id)
                If IsNothing(UserProfile) Then
                    Return HttpNotFound()
                End If


                db.Entry(UserProfile).State = EntityState.Modified
                db.SaveChanges()

                Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")
            Catch e As MembershipCreateUserException

                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode))
            End Try
        End Using
    End If
```

It seems to be working, except that it's appending dbo. in front of the Table name instead of the halifax. that I've got in my schema.  How do I tell it what to use there?  If I put in a dbo. table, the code runs, but it puts the profile information in the wrong place.

Comment: "Invalid object name 'dbo.UserProfile'" is the InnerException it's throwing.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to infer two questions here

**1.** How to change the default schema (dbo) so that table is created under new schema name (halifax)?

Answer: It appears you are using SimpleMembershipProvider (SMP) and internally

> WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection

uses the default schema "dbo" assigned to your database User to create\access the tables 
for the SimpleMembershipProvider.

So you will be required to make few changes to let SMP know that it should create table in a particular schema.

I did not found a direct way with SMP to tell it to create UserProfile table in a particular schema.

How I achieved this is by creating my own SMP classes like below:

```
[Table("UserProfile", Schema = "Halifax")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string EmailId { get; set; }
}
```

Please note the schema name added to Table attribute.

You can find full instructions on how to add [Simple Membership Tables as Part of Your Entity Framework](http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/including-asp-net-simple-membership-tables-as-part-of-your-entity-framework-model).

**2.** From the subject of this question I could infer that you would like to add more columns into the default tables e.g. UserProfile.

Answer: As mentioned above, in order to include additional information in the SMP tables, you will have to create your own equivalent classes and add extra columns in the class. Please note I have added EmailId into the UserProfile table above. If you follow this [article](http://www.itorian.com/2013/03/PasswordResetting.html#comment-form) (although it intend to cover a different aspect of SMP) you will find instructions to add custom fields. Hope this helps.

Update:

This is how I achieved this in VB (After dozens of try :))

```
<Table("UserProfile", Schema:="Halifax")>
Public Class UserProfile
    <Key>
    <DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)>
    Public Property UserId() As Integer

    Public Property UserName() As String

    <MaxLength(100)>
    Public Property EmailId() As String
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks much!  I'll vote you up as soon as I have enough reputation myself to do that!

1.  This is pretty much the answer I found in a couple of places around the web, but forgive me, the C# code isn't working in vb.  The VB line I needed to modify looks like this:
    <Table("UserProfile")>_
    Public Class UserProfile
and 
    <Table("UserProfile",Schema "Dbo")>_
    Public Class UserProfile
apparently isn't proper syntax for VB.  I've tried about 3 dozen permutations, and can't find one that works.

Comment: Maybe the goal of writing my MVC in VBA to keep code portability with my VB application that works with the same DB is overly optimistic...

2.  Adding extra columns was simple enough, both in the DB table itself, and in the model, view, and controller.

Comment: @JoeBearden - I am glad my answer helped you. I tried this here in a VB project (I use C# mostly for development) and after dozen of tries :), was able to create the table with desired schema. Please see updated answer.

Comment: :=   

Really?  Really?!
Amazing.  Thank you SO much for the help.  I never, ever would have figured that out!

Comment: @JoeBearden - You are welcome Joe. If this answers your questions, you can set it as answer ;)